# What term would describe the following poetry elements like rhyme, alliteration, assonance, etc. that relate to the way the word is sounded?

Tags: rhymes, alliteration

I'm looking for a word that categorizes rhyme, alliteration, assonance, etc. that relate to the way the word is sounded into one group/word. I hear that it could be called "sound devices" because they are utilized for their sound aspect in poetry, but it seems there may be a more technical linguistic term maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure how *spelling* is involved. Don't you mean the way they *sound*"?  English spelling is often non-phonetic.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That's true. I will re-edit the question from "What term would describe the following poetry elements like rhyme, alliteration, assonance, etc. that relate to the way the word is spelled?" to "What term would describe the following poetry elements like rhyme, alliteration, assonance, etc. that relate to the way the word is sounded?"

Comment: This link describes them as "Elements of poetry"  -  https://sevencircumstances.com/poetry-and-lyrics/elements-of-poetry/elements-of-poetry-rhyme-alliteration-assonance-consonance/

Comment: Don't even mention spelling. Poetry is aural.

Comment: Poetry is primarily but not exclusively aural/oral. Many poets use effects in written language, from [eye rhyme](https://poemanalysis.com/literary-device/eye-rhyme/) to shape poems and [concrete poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_poetry).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [prosody](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prosody) is what you're looking for.

> noun
>
> 1 the science or study of poetic meters and versification.
>
> 2 a particular or distinctive system of metrics and versification:
> Milton's prosody.
>
> 3 Linguistics. the stress and intonation patterns of an utterance.

Comment: Prosody describes some sound techniques, like meter, rhythm, and stress, but not others (e.g. alliteration).

Answer (score 1):

The collective term *sound devices*, as you've heard, is correct.
In relation to poetry, it refers to all aspects of  the *choice and arrangement* of words by a writer of poetry or prose, designed to have a desired effect on the human ear. These are also called *aural devices* in literature.

Answer (score 0):

**Poetic Device**

> At its most basic, a **poetic device** is a deliberate use of words,
> phrases, sounds, and even shapes to convey meaning. That sounds so
> broad that it could basically encompass any form of written
> expression, but poetic devices are generally used to heighten the
> literal meaning of words by considering sound, form, and function.
>
> *The 20 Poetic Devices You Must Know by Melissa Brinks*
>
> https://blog.prepscholar.com/poetic-devices-poetry-terms

Comment: This is useful but does not actually answer the question.

Comment: Some poetic devices involve sound, but others do not (e.g. metaphor, personification, shape poetry). The quotation actually agrees with me.

Answer (score -1):

How about **cadence**?

Noun

a rhythmic sequence or flow of sounds in language
Example: the grand **cadence** of his poetry

(Merriam-Webster)